# reconnect function is missing in documentation when connection is lost

Tags: angular, signalr

I am using this library for signalr in my angular 5 application
https://github.com/HNeukermans/ng2-signalr

the signalr gets disconnected after certain period of time. I don't see any documentation how to reconnect from client side.
please help if anyone know how to do it

Comment: Do you have anymore information to give on why it disconnects?  Or anything else that fires this disconnection?

Comment: when user starts browsing another tabs and left opened my site in another tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest on an error you can apply settimeout to restart or start the connection again.

```
this.connection.errors.subscribe((error: any) => {
     this.errors.push(error);
console.log('Error while establishing connection... Retrying...');
    setTimeout(() => this.connection.start(), 3000);
});
```

or else you can aspnet/signal [HubConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49591843/how-can-i-keep-trying-to-subscribe-to-signalr-from-angular-service-if-connection)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom retry but not sure if it works. Listen for connection status, with:

```
this.connection.status.subscribe((status: ConnectionStatus) => {
     this.statuses.push(status);
});
```

on Error, after some delay call connection start again.

**OR** you can use Microsoft's official lib for SignalR: [aspnet/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr) instead of ng2-signalr. It's really simple to use with Angular. Checkout these articles:

- [Getting Started With SignalR, .NET Core 2.1 And Angular](https://passos.com.au/signalr-with-net-core-2-1-and-angular/)
- [How to notify your Angular 5 app using SignalR](https://medium.com/@rukshandangalla/how-to-notify-your-angular-5-app-using-signalr-5e5aea2030b2)